# Please explain perl operator associativity

Tags: perl

The [DOC](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) explains perl operator precedence and associativity. I am interesting at `->` and `*` operators. Both have `left` associativity.

I have next example and it seems that `->` has right associativity. **Not left** as documentation states:

```
my @args;
sub call { print "call\n"; shift @args }
sub test { print "test\n"; 1 }
sub t4 { print "t4\n"; 4 }

@args=( \&test, 2, 3 );
call()->( @args, t4 );


sub m1 { print "m1\n"; 2 }
sub m2 { print "m2\n"; 4 }

m1()*(@args, m2);
```

The output is:

```
t4
call
test
m1
m2
```

**Because `->` has left associativity I expect next output:**

```
call
t4
test
m1
m2
```

What did I miss? Why `t4` is called before `call`?

Comment: The arguments to the `->` call is evaluated first (i.e. `t4()`), then `call()` is called, then finally `call()` returns a coderef (`test()`) that is called

Comment: @HåkonHægland: But in case of `*` there first `m1()` then `m2`. So in case of `->` I also expect `call` then `t4`

Comment: Good point. I think this is explained by the answers below.. `$ref->(@args)` is a TERM according to [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html), and it is not specified whether `$ref` or `@args` will be evaluated first. In this case it happens that `@args` is evaluated first.

Comment: @HåkonHægland: so for both operators `TERMS` are evaluated in different order.

Comment: That is not associativity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asking about *operand evaluation order* (the order in which operands are evaluated), not *operator associativity* (the order in which operators of the same *operator precedence* are evaluated).

The operand evaluation order is undefined (or at least undocumented) for many operators, including `->`. You will find it consistent, but one shouldn't rely on that.

You can use statement breaks to force the desired order:

```
my $sub = call();
$sub->( @args, t4 );
```

This would also work:

```
$_->( @args, t4 ) for call();
```

---

### Operator Associativity

Associativity is the order in which operators of the same precedence are evaluated.

For example, `*` and `/` have the same precedence, so associativity determines that

```
 3 / 4 * 5 * 6
```

is equivalent to

```
 ( ( 3 / 4 ) * 5 ) * 6 = 22.5
```

and not

```
 3 / ( 4 * ( 5 * 6 ) ) = 0.025
```

As you can see, associativity can have a direct effect on the outcome of the expression.

---

### Operand Evaluation Order

Operand evaluation order is the order in which operands are evaluated.

For example, operand evaluation order determines whether `1+2` is evaluated before `3+4`, or vice-versa in

```
( 1 + 2 ) * ( 3 + 4 )
```

Unless evaluating the operand has a side-effect (e.g. changing a variable or printing to the screen), then operand evaluation order has no effect on the outcome of the expression. As such, some languages leave it undefined to allow for optimization.

In Perl, it's undefined (or at least undocumented) for many operators. It's only documented for the following:

- The comma operator (`,` and `=>`): left to right
- Binary boolean operators (`and`, `or`, `&&`, `||` and `//`): left, then maybe right<sup>[1]</sup>
- Conditional operators (`? :`): left, then either second or third<sup>[1]</sup>
- List and scalar assignment operators (`=`): right, then left<sup>[2]</sup>
- Binding operators (`=~` and `!~`): left, then right<sup>[3]</sup>

---

1. Required for short-circuited evaluation.
2. Required for `my $x = $x;`.
3. Required to function at all.

Comment: So if for `->` operator the operand evaluation order is not documented I should not relay on `shift->( @_ )` should I?

Comment: Right. Both using and changing a variable in an expression should usually be avoided. You could use `$_[0]->(@_[1..$#_])`

Answer (score 3):

Associativity is a rule that tells you how to parse an expression where the same operator appears twice, or more than one operator with the same precedence level appears. For example, associativity determines that:

```
foo()->bar()->baz()
```

is equivalent to

```
(foo()->bar())->baz() # left associative
```

and not

```
foo()->(bar()->baz()) # right associative
```

Since your code only hase one `->` operator in it, the associativity of that operator is irrelevant.

You seem to be looking for a rule about the order of evaluation of operands to the `->` operator. As far as I know, there is no guaranteed order of evaluation for most operators in perl (much like C). If the order matters, you should split the expression into multiple statements with an explicit temporary variable:

```
my $tmp = call();
$tmp->( @args, t4 );
```

Comment: associativity define the order. do not? Look at @DaveSherohman example: `(a->b)->c`, so `(a)->b` and not `a->(b)` because of left associativity

Comment: Associativity defines how the operations are placed into a parse tree. Some ordering constraints are implied by the parse tree, but the evaluation of the leaf operands can still happen in any order. If you want to argue that the order is well defined by parentheses and associativity, you need to explain why the rule you use for `->` doesn't apply to the `*`

Comment: By the way, one problem we face with perl is that as a single-implementation language, there's no clear line between officially defined behavior and coincidence. [Even the people who work on the perl core occasionally disagree with each other on how much of the evaluation order is guaranteed.](http://grokbase.com/t/perl/perl5-porters/107f90pnbn/order-of-evaluation-of-terms-was-peephole-optimiser-could-prune-more-dead-code/oldest)

Answer (score 2):

Associativity describes the order that multiple operators of equal precedence are handled. It has nothing to do with whether the left arguments or the right arguments are processed first. `->` being left associative means that `a->b->c` is processed as `(a->b)->c`, not as `a->(b->c)`.

Comment: If the parentheses had an effect on the evaluation order, `m2` would be called before `m1`. I think order is just not specified.

Comment: Re "*The reason the parenthesized argument list gets processed first is because parentheses are higher-precedence than `->`.*",  Totally wrong. Demo: `perl -E'say("abc") + (say("def") + say("ghi"))'`

Comment: @ikegami Well, that's... interesting. Incorrect statement removed, but it would be nice to have an explanation of what's really going on, then. (But it seems unlikely that any such explanation is documented, so I doubt we'll ever get one, aside from the pragmatic "UTSL".)

Comment: See my answer if you want an explanation

Comment: @ikegami I read "undefined (or at least undocumented) for many operators, including `->`" as more of a statement that we don't have an explanation of how it's ordered and aren't likely to get one.

Comment: Then you misread. It means there's no official order. You can't explain something that doesn't exist. I even explained why there might not be an official order.

Comment: I think I see now. You're talking about the _official_ order, I'm talking about the _actual_ order. There is an actual order. That order is deterministic. There is a cause for that order. This cause can be explained and (probably) understood, even if it is not official, nor documented, nor intentional. ("Probably" because it could be the emergent result of a set of extremely complex interactions. But I don't think that's likely in this case.)

Comment: Re "*I'm talking about the actual order.*", It's silly to discuss the order of evaluation of a specific operator in a specific program in a specific run on a specific machine. No, it would not be "nice" to include this. /// Re "*That order is deterministic*", No, not necessarily. /// Re "*There is a cause for that order*", No, not necessarily.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141509/discussion-between-dave-sherohman-and-ikegami).